# PHP form - if 2 radio buttons are selected

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a very simple HTML form on a PHP page for a questionnaire.

10 yes/no questions. Radio buttons.

I am trying to figure out how to show a hidden div if any 2 of the radio buttons are set to 'yes'.

would i be better off using a jquery script, or PHP?

Comment: jQuery. Why? Because you want to intercept client side interaction, and for that, you use a client side language. JavaScript (jQuery framework) is a client language, as opposed to PHP, which is a server side language.

Comment: Presumably he means 10 sets of 2 radio button families. Pretty standard Yes/No architecture if you ask me.

Comment: @adam yeah, that makes much more sense, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP could only do it if you roundtrip the form through the server after every button click, which'd still require Javascript to detect the click and submit the form for revamping.

Remember that PHP runs on the server. By the time the user sees the form and is clicking around on it, PHP has long since completed its job and has shut down.

In other words, you need to use Javascript for this.

Comment: I don't see how what you write is true, of course it is possible with PHP. You don't need any JS for "submitting and revamping".

Comment: @markus: ok. you click two radio buttons in the form. How does PHP know you've clicked them, so it can send out the commands to show the div? Last few billion times I looked, clicking a radio button does NOT trigger a form submission, unless there's JS involved.

Comment: That's not my point. My point is, you can show the additional div after submit, if two or more questions have been answered with yes.

Comment: @markus: yes, exactly, but that requires a full server roundtrip. Not exactly user friendly. "If you select any two radio buttons, please click on submit so I can show you some hidden content".

Comment: Sure, if the new content has to critically appear just after exactly 2 yes answers have been given, it would not work. But if it doesn't matter if 2, 3, or more yes answers have been given. It would be just like a follow up question. Usability wasn't my focus.

Comment: @Markus He asked which way is best.  It's true that he can do this in PHP but given the format of the question javascript is probably best (and jQuery would be overkill)

Comment: You should use progressive enhancement and implement it on the server-side first (PHP) and then the client-side for eye candy (Javascript). Otherwise, people with Javascript disabled won't see the message.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it without submitting the form, you have to do it with Javascript. If you don't mind another roundtrip, you can do it with PHP.

You're not "better off" either way. It depends on what you want to do and how important the feature is.

With JS you can store the number of selected "yes" options in a variable and as soon as this variable is 2 or higher, you toggle the additional content div.

With PHP you analyze the $_POST array, count the "yes" answers and send the same page to the client including the additional div plus the already selected answers.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably be better off using jQuery and handling it client side.

Something like:

```
$(function () {
    $(".radioClass").change(function () {
        // check through all radio buttons for YES / NO
        // toggle div visibility appropriately
    });
});
```